# how to show a text value in a column in gridview in .net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView to show user detail like name,phone,and status(active,suspend).
my problem is that in database the user status in from of integer like 1 for Active and 0 for suspend.now while i am showing data to user in GridView I want to show Active and suspend Text according to status in database 1 or 0. I am not getting where to check for this condition in Asp.Net I am new in asp. I have done it in php also.

like

```
if($fetch->user_status==1) 
  echo "Active" 
else 
  echo "suspend"
```

please help me how to do this in asp
with gridview control..

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this for your `GridView` column

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText='Status'>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserStatus"))==0?"Suspended":"Active"'/>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do in situations like this is to create a helper function that renders the text to be displayed something like this.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText='Status'>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DisplayUserStatus(Eval("UserStatus")))'/>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

Public Function DisplayUserStatus(UserStatus as String) as String

  Select Case UserStatus
   Case "1"
     Return "Active"
   Case  "0"
     Return "Suspended"
   Case Else
     Return "Unknown"
  End Select

End Function
```

In my opinion it looks much cleaner than putting logic into the aspx page, plus makes the code more maintainable in the future, say for example you want to add a new type of User Status, its just a case of adding to the case statment. If using inline code this can quickly get out of hand.